# Run a Parallel PHP Application with Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I have a PHP based application that runs on the Google Maps API.  Most of it is written in straight PHP and Javascript, but I want to use some sort of CMS or tool to upload images, because there will be large numbers of images and categories to go with those images. So I want to use the "Media" portion of Wordpress to add/edit/delete images and then use some sort of Wordpress tag to add them to the page.  Any insights as to the best way to do this?

Comment: You can't just use "the "Media" portion of Wordpress" anymore than you can just use the "transmission portion" of a car without dismantling the car and building a new structure around it. That is a pretty broad request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/media/) plugin to add/manipulate/present media of a WordPress install from within your app. The page creation part I am not sure of, perhaps it'll need to be done manually - or you can create pages [via the `/pages/` endpoint](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/pages/).

I'll let someone correct me if I'm wrong, but the API endpoints (which are available at the link as a plugin) either made it into core already, or are really close to it.